# SSRS - Is it possible to export to Excel with a custom Excel format for a value?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, formatting

I have a report that has a currency value in a matrix and it exports to Excel with the $ sign in front of the number. The request is that when it exports, it actually is a custom Excel format of "*($* #,##0*);*($* (#,##0);*($* "-"??*);*(@_)" so it aligns the dollar sign to the left and the value to the right of the cell. Is there a way to do this in SSRS so upon export, it automatically formats the number like this?

Comment: Sort the format once it is in excel...

Comment: There's like 50+ sheets... the point is to remove that step and have it done automatically

Comment: Then don't tag excel if you don't want to consider excel as the solution...

Comment: Then provide an actual solution to the question I asked. The key word being "automatically", your proposal doesn't fit this.

Comment: It could do if you applied vba...

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can see this working, is to format your currency cell as an HTML placeholder and have the value of that cell as something like...

```
="£" & CHR(160) & chr(160) & chr(160) & chr(160) & "100"
```

... replacing your data accordingly.
There isn't a way to control the export as you require, but this will get you close.